# Question about $\gcd$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, divisibility

> **Theorem:** Let $K$ be an infinite field and let $L:=K(\alpha, \beta)/K$ be a field extension with $\alpha$ algebraic over $K$ and $\beta$ separable over $K$. Then $L = K(z)$ for a certain $z \in L$.
>
> **Proof:** Let $f,g$ be the minimal polynomials over $K$ of $\alpha, \beta$ respectively and $M/L$ the splitting field of $fg$.
>
> Denote by $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_m$ the roots of $f$ in $M$ and $\beta_1, \ldots, \beta_n$ the roots of $g$ in $M$.
>
> Since $K$ is infinite, there exists a $c \in K$ such that $c\alpha_i+\beta_j$ are all different. Pose $z := c\alpha+\beta \in L$ and $h(x) := g(z-cx) \in K(z)[x]$.
>
> Then $h(\alpha) = 0 = f(\alpha)$ and $(x-\alpha)|\gcd(f,h)$. It can be verified that $\alpha$ is the only common root of $f$ and $h$. Since $f$ is separable, $\gcd(f,h) = x-\alpha$.
>
> Now $x-\alpha \in K(z)[x]$ so in particular $\alpha \in K(z)$ and $\beta = z-c\alpha \in K(z)$.
>
> Therefore... $\square$

**Question:** *A priori*, we may seek $\gcd(f,h)$ either in $M[x]$ or in $K(z)[x]$. But $\alpha$ is not known to be in $K(z)$ yet, so what tells us that the $\gcd$ of $f$ and $h$ in $K(z)[x]$ is also $x-\alpha$ and not, say, $1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look at $f$ and $h$ in some splitting field. They have $x-\alpha$ as a common factor. Now the gcd can be calculated algebraically from $f$ and $g$ by Euclid's algorithm. Thus this gcd will be in any field that contains the coefficients of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: I understand that applying Euclid's algorithm will give a $\gcd$, call it $r_n$, of $f,g \in M[x]$ that is in $K(z)[x]$ since $f,g \in K(z)[x]$. But, isn't it true that $x-\alpha$ might differ by a unity from $r_n$, and since this unity is possibly in $M\backslash K(z)$, then possibly $x-\alpha \not\in K(z)[x]$?

Comment: You still get something of the form $ax+b$ so both $a$ and $b$ are in your field.

Comment: Oh, ok. If I get it right, there might be more $\gcd$s of $f$ and $h$ when we see $f,h \in M[x]$ instead of $f,h \in K(z)[x]$, but the *monic* $\gcd$ will be in $K(z)[x]$. That's why you said "*this* $\gcd$ will be in any field that contains the coefficients of $f$ and $h$". In this case we would have $\alpha = -a^{-1}b \in K(z)$.

Comment: Yes regardless of how the Euclid algorithm turns out you get $\alpha$.